# How can I write two update queries in single stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a few columns bound to a gridview.

In that gridview, I have an edit option to update the columns. In that situation I need to write a two update stored procedures that means I select all columns expect `AudiotoName`, select another columns all columns are update to raise one update query but when I select table in that have `AudiotoName` column that only edit to select that column it will raise second update stored procedure. I tried but it not properly working can anyone help me out.

My code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE up_file
    (@ModuleID int,
     @SubjectID int,
     @Physician varchar(500) = '',
     @AuditoName varchar(300) = '',
     @AuditoType varchar(50) = '',
     @AudioPath varchar(2000) = '',
     @BaseDocumentName varchar(500) = '',
     @BaseDocumentPath varchar(2000) = '',
     @Createddate datetime, 
     @CreatedBy varchar(200) = '')
AS
BEGIN   
    IF @AuditoName = 'true' //select AuditoName column only raise this update query
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SubjectItems 
        SET ModuleID = @ModuleID,
            SubjectID = @SubjectID,
            Physician = '@Physician',
            AuditoName = '@AuditoName',
            AuditoType = '@AuditoType',
            AudioPath ='@AudioPath',
            BaseDocumentName = '@BaseDocumentName',
            BaseDocumentPath = '@BaseDocumentPath' 
         WHERE AuditoName = @AuditoName
    END
    BEGIN  //normal fields select raise this update query 
       UPDATE SubjectItems 
       SET ModuleID = @ModuleID,
            SubjectID = @SubjectID,
            Physician = '@Physician',
            AuditoName = '@AuditoName',
            AuditoType = '@AuditoType',
            AudioPath ='@AudioPath',
            BaseDocumentName = '@BaseDocumentName',
            BaseDocumentPath = '@BaseDocumentPath' 
         WHERE ModuleID = @ModuleID
    END
END
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your query is that, even if `@AuditoName` is true, the lower update query is running. This will re-update the table `SubjectItems`. You can use `if...else` block instead, like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE up_file
    (@ModuleID int,
     @SubjectID int,
     @Physician varchar(500) = '',
     @AuditoName varchar(300) = '',
     @AuditoType varchar(50) = '',
     @AudioPath varchar(2000) = '',
     @BaseDocumentName varchar(500) = '',
     @BaseDocumentPath varchar(2000) = '',
     @Createddate datetime, 
     @CreatedBy varchar(200) = '')
AS
BEGIN   
    IF @AuditoName = 'true' //select AuditoName column only raise this update query
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SubjectItems 
        SET ModuleID = @ModuleID,
            SubjectID = @SubjectID,
            Physician = '@Physician',
            AuditoName = '@AuditoName',
            AuditoType = '@AuditoType',
            AudioPath ='@AudioPath',
            BaseDocumentName = '@BaseDocumentName',
            BaseDocumentPath = '@BaseDocumentPath' 
         WHERE AuditoName = @AuditoName
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN  //normal fields select raise this update query 
       UPDATE SubjectItems 
       SET ModuleID = @ModuleID,
            SubjectID = @SubjectID,
            Physician = '@Physician',
            AuditoName = '@AuditoName',
            AuditoType = '@AuditoType',
            AudioPath ='@AudioPath',
            BaseDocumentName = '@BaseDocumentName',
            BaseDocumentPath = '@BaseDocumentPath' 
         WHERE ModuleID = @ModuleID
    END
END
```